# Analytic Continuation

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

For the part underlined in green, the solution implies that this can be seen immediately? When I proved a similar result that:

$\Gamma(z)=\frac{\Gamma(z+1)}{z} \forall z$

using analytic continuation a fair amount of working was required.

Comment: for $w$ fixed, $g_w(z) = B(z,w)$, clearly the fact that $g_w(z) =\frac{\Gamma(z) \Gamma(w)}{\Gamma(z+w)}$ for $Re(z) > 0$ allows one to extend analytically for every $z$ where the RHS is defined : this is because $\frac{\Gamma(z) \Gamma(w)}{\Gamma(z+w)}$ is meromorphic in $z$.  but then I don't get what you ask. do you have any representation for $B(z,w)$ other than the integral representation when $Re(z) > 0$ and $Re(w) > 0$ ?

Comment: because this is the problem : proving that the analytic continuation of some representation will give the same result as another representation, whenever the two are equal on some non empty open set (and I'm talking of functions of one  complex variable)

Comment: If two meromorphic functions coincide on an open set (or easier, a set with an accumulation point) then they agree everywhere. This is the identity theorem.